# Proving Gauge invariance of Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, gauge-invariance

I am trying to proof explicitly that Schrodinger equation:
$$ i\hbar \partial_t \psi = \left[ -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2+qV \right]\psi$$

remains the same under the following gauge transformation:

$$ \psi \rightarrow e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi$$
$$ \vec{A} \rightarrow \vec{A} + \nabla \Lambda$$
$$ V \rightarrow V - \partial_t\Lambda$$

where $\partial_t$ stands for the time derivative operator.

However, I am having problems with the algebra, so I will show my procedure with the hopes that someone point to an error:

**Left side of equation**
$$ i\hbar \partial_t (e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\psi) = ih \left(e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \partial_t\psi+\frac{iq}{\hbar}e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi \partial_t\Lambda \right) = ihe^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \partial_t\psi-qe^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi \partial_t\Lambda  $$

**Right side of equation**
$$ \left[ \frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q(\vec{A} + \nabla \Lambda)\right)^2+q(V - \partial_t\Lambda) \right]= $$
$$ \frac{1}{2m} \left[ -\hbar^2\nabla^2-\frac{q\hbar}{i}( \nabla \cdot\vec{A} + \nabla^2\Lambda+ \vec{A} \cdot \nabla + \nabla \Lambda \cdot \nabla)  + q^2[\vec{A}^2+2(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda) + (\nabla \Lambda )^2]\right] e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi +qV e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi
 -qe^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi \partial_t\Lambda $$

It is possible to observe that the last term in both (the right and left) sides cancel each other.
*Then, using:*

$\nabla ( e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi ) =  e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\nabla\psi + \frac{iq}{h} \psi \nabla \Lambda$

$ \nabla^2 ( e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi ) =e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \nabla^2\psi + \frac{2iq}{\hbar}e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}(\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi) + \psi \frac{iq}{\hbar} e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \nabla^2 \Lambda - \frac{q^2}{\hbar^2}\psi e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}  (\nabla \Lambda)^2 $

we then obtain (by applying operators and canceling all the $e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}$ ):

$$ i\hbar \partial_t \psi= \frac{1}{2m} \left[  -\hbar^2 \nabla^2 \psi - 2iqh(\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi)-iq\hbar \psi \nabla^2\Lambda + q^2\psi(\nabla \Lambda)^2 + iq\hbar (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})\psi + iq\hbar\nabla^2\Lambda \psi +iq\hbar (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla\psi) - q^2 \psi (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda )+iq\hbar (\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi) - q^2\psi (\nabla\Lambda)^2+q^2\vec{A}^2+2q^2(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda)\psi +q^2(\nabla \Lambda)^2 \psi  \right] + qV\psi$$

cancelling some terms, and rearranging:

$$ i\hbar \partial_t \psi= \frac{1}{2m} \left[  -\hbar^2 \nabla^2 \psi + iq\hbar (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})\psi +iq\hbar (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla\psi)+q^2\vec{A}^2 - 2iqh(\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi) + q^2\psi(\nabla \Lambda)^2- q^2 \psi (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda )+iq\hbar (\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi)   +2q^2(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda)\psi  \right] + qV\psi  $$

after more reordering:

$$ i\hbar \partial_t \psi=  \frac{1}{2m} \left[ \left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2 \right] +qV\psi + \frac{1}{2m} \left[  - iqh(\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi) + q^2\psi(\nabla \Lambda)^2 + q^2(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda)\psi  \right]$$

It is possible to observe that the original schrodinger equation is up there, but with an extra part in the right side, this extra part is:
$$ \frac{1}{2m} \left[  - iqh(\nabla \Lambda)(\nabla \psi) + q^2\psi(\nabla \Lambda)^2 + q^2(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla \Lambda)\psi  \right]$$

So am wondering, is this extra part some how 0, or am I making a mistake. Also I don't know how to make the algebra "nicer" to follow, if there is anything I can do please comment.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94699/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94699/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245531/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92885/226902.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, Schroedinger equation
$$ -i\hbar \partial_t \psi+ \left[ -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2+qV \right]\psi=0\tag{0}$$
under the gauge transformations

$$ \psi \rightarrow \psi'= e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar} \psi$$
$$ \vec{A} \rightarrow \vec{A}' = \vec{A} + \nabla \Lambda$$
$$ V \rightarrow V'= V - \partial_t\Lambda$$

does not remain invariant, but the left-hand side of (0) gives rise to
$$  -i\hbar \partial_t \psi'+ \left[ -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}'\right)^2+qV' \right]\psi'=
e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\left\{-i\hbar \partial_t \psi+ \left[ -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2+qV \right]\psi\right\}\:.$$

In summary, since $e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\neq 0$,

$\qquad\quad$ *gauge transformed quantities  satisfy Schroedinger equation if untranformed quantities do.*

To prove it, avoid *brute force* computations as yours which give rise to unavoidable mistakes almost certainly  and go on as follows.  First rewrite the initial equation as
$$ -\left[i\hbar \partial_t -qV \right]\psi  -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2\psi=0\tag{1}$$
Next notice that, under the transformations, we have

$$\left[i\hbar \partial_t -qV' \right]\psi' =
\left[i\hbar \partial_t -q(V - \partial_t\Lambda)\right]e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\psi  =
e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\left[i\hbar \partial_t -qV \right]\psi $$
and
$$\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}'\right)\psi'  = \left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q(\vec{A} +\nabla \Lambda)\right)e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\psi =  e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)\psi$$
so that, iterating the second result
$$\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}'\right)^2\psi'   =  e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2\psi\:.$$
Putting  all together, under the action of gauge transformations, (1) becomes
$$ -\left[i\hbar \partial_t -qV' \right]\psi'  -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}'\right)^2\psi' =
e^{iq\Lambda/\hbar}\left\{-\left[i\hbar \partial_t -qV \right]\psi -\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec{A}\right)^2\psi\right\}=0$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y3qcKzO_mY)  by the great Barton Zwiebach from MIT lectures.

He does exactle what you are doing in a 20 min video, if the link stop working, it is Lecture L14.1 from the MIT course 8.06 Quantum Physics III, Spring 2018, which you will always find on Youtube or in [the MIT lectures web](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/resources/l14-1/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/382733)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write it as a comment in the other answers, which is essentially what the video does, but I don't have enough reputation yet :(.

I'lll make a superquick summary in the answer, whenever I can.