# In Schrodinger Equation Local $U(1)$ Gauge Invariance, How is Laplacian Simplified?

Tags: electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

So I'm trying to derive the conditions necessary for local $U(1)$ gauge invariance in the Schrodinger equation, and I don't understand how Laplacian of the wavefunction is simplified the way it is. So the transformation is:

\begin{equation}
\psi \rightarrow \psi'=\psi e^{i\lambda(x,t)}
\end{equation}

Which gives the following Laplacian which I understand:

\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\psi'=(\nabla^2+2i\nabla\lambda\cdot\nabla+i\nabla^2\lambda - (\nabla\lambda)^2)\psi. \tag{1} 
\end{equation}

According to every textbook I read, the next step is to simplify it the following way:

\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\psi'=(\nabla+i\nabla\lambda)^2\psi 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(\nabla+i\nabla\lambda)^2\psi=(\nabla^2+i\nabla\lambda\cdot\nabla+i\nabla^2\lambda-(\nabla\lambda)^2)\psi. \tag{2} 
\end{equation}

However, equation (1) and equation (2) are not the same because the 2 present in the second term of equation (1) is not in equation (2). Is there some piece of algebra I am missing? Here is a reference: [http://www.niser.ac.in/~sbasak/p303_2010/23.11.pdf](http://www.niser.ac.in/%7Esbasak/p303_2010/23.11.pdf) (page 2)

Comment: Schrödinger's equation is not invariant when transforming only $\psi$.
You simultaneously need to transform the potentials $\vec{A}$ and $V$.
See [Proving Gauge invariance of Schrodinger Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439550/proving-gauge-invariance-of-schrodinger-equation).

Comment: I know, but this is simply just to see what it does to the Schrodinger equation. This is similar to what I'm doing: http://www.niser.ac.in/~sbasak/p303_2010/23.11.pdf (top of page 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a little error in my calculation, I basically neglected the product rule in the $\nabla(i(\nabla\lambda)\psi)$ term because I treated the operator as a scalar. So I really should be thinking about simplifying this in terms of operating on the function so I don't make this mistake again:

$$(\nabla+i\nabla\lambda)^2\psi=\nabla^2\psi+\nabla(i(\nabla\lambda)\cdot\psi)+i(\nabla\lambda)\nabla\psi-(\nabla\lambda)^2\psi$$
$$=\nabla^2\psi+i(\nabla^2\lambda)\psi+i(\nabla\lambda)\nabla\psi+i(\nabla\lambda)\nabla\psi-(\nabla\lambda)^2\psi$$
$$=\nabla^2\psi+i(\nabla^2\lambda)\psi+2i(\nabla\lambda)\nabla\psi-(\nabla\lambda)^2\psi$$
Therefore:
$$(\nabla+i\nabla\lambda)^2=\nabla^2+i(\nabla^2\lambda)+2i(\nabla\lambda)\nabla-(\nabla\lambda)^2$$